# Warning occuring in xgboost

Tags: python, xgboost

i'm solving the multi-classification problem using xgboost.

But, Warnings occured when fitting xgboost model.

My code is as follows. I'm using xgboost 1.4.0

```
start = time.time()


xgb_model = xgboost.XGBClassifier(tree_method='gpu_hist', eta = 0.2, nrounds= 1000, 
                                  colsample_bytree=0.5, 
                                  metric='multi:softmax') 


hr_pred = xgb_model.fit(x_train, np.ravel(y_train, order='C')).predict(x_test)

print(classification_report(y_test, hr_pred))

print(time.time()-start)
```

result comes out well. But this Warnings pops up.

```
Parameters: { "metric", "nrounds" } might not be used.

  This may not be accurate due to some parameters are only used in language bindings but
  passed down to XGBoost core.  Or some parameters are not used but slip through this
  verification. Please open an issue if you find above cases.


UserWarning: Use subset (sliced data) of np.ndarray is not recommended because it will generate extra copies and increase memory consumption
  "because it will generate extra copies and increase " +
```

1. Even if it's not accurate, I don't know what it means to be passed down to the XGBoost core.
2. Where did I use the subset of ndarray?

Comment: This warning occurs with their regressor, as well. Perhaps you want to open an issue on GitHub?

Comment: If I can solve this warning i will. but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I find the solution of downgrading rather risky.

Instead, you can suppress this particular warning quite easily with `warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=UserWarning)`.

Unfortunately, according to the devs, this is expected behaviour.
https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/6908

Comment: where should `warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=UserWarning)` be written? Adding that code into my Python script generates an error: `NameError: name 'warnings' is not defined`

Comment: `import warnings` will help :) 
You can just do it in your own script where you call xgb.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a temporary fix, but `pip uninstall xgboost` then `pip install xgboost==1.3.3` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code snippet at the top of your script.  The message is a regular expression matching the unwanted warning message.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action="ignore", message=r'.*Use subset.*of np.ndarray is not recommended')
```